# Backbone Template Options

Tags: templates, backbone.js

I'm reading about backbone.js and one of the issues I've encountered is the templating system.

My issue is, the example I've seen use the notation of `<% %>` in the templates.

Unfortunately, this syntax is also used by Mason-Perl which is what we're using on the backend so this collides.  Is there any way to define the syntax OR are there any other template options that do not use `<% %>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Backbone uses [Underscore's template function](http://underscorejs.org/#template). You can modify Underscore's template settings to use symbols other than `<% %>`:

> If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change
>   Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off
>   interpolated code. Define an interpolate regex to match expressions
>   that should be interpolated verbatim, an escape regex to match
>   expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped, and an
>   evaluate regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without
>   insertion into the resulting string. You may define or omit any
>   combination of the three. For example, to perform Mustache.js style
>   templating:
>
> ```
> _.templateSettings = {
>   interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
> };
>
> var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
> template({name: "Mustache"});
> => "Hello Mustache!"
> ```